# Can I take a design done in Sketch and transfer it into Xcode's Storyboard?

Tags: xcode

I designed my apps UI using Sketch. Is there a way to transfer it directly into Xcode ie the storyboard? Or do I have to recreate the design from scratch using Xcode's Storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

I've done it in pieces using Sketches, a program similar to Sketch. I exported each drawing from Sketches as a JPEG and then added the file in Xcode. You might want to use some intermediary program (such as Preview) to change the size of the drawing to exactly whatever you need for the app. If you've created an entire drawing of the proposed screen, you can use it as the background for a screen-sized imageView. Then you can place the appropriate UI elements and re-size them to match. Delete the imageView. With Auto Layout, you can set it to use the Canvas values to generate constraints as needed.